Name of a sci-fi movie/tv series from the 80s?
There is this movie or tv series from the 80s about a group of children near a lake that find an ancient device that was put there by some ancient civilization. This device protects the earth from another race of hostile aliens that wanted to intrude the earth (yet in the end they didn't).
But now these group of kids must make the device stop working or it will attack the descendants of these ancients who built it.
It is a sci-fi genre from the 80s or 70s  
The device these ancient aliens left on earth is located in a cave near this lake. This device is called "the guardian". When it works, there is a lot of steam from the lake water...
Movie time: in the 70s or the 80s
Country: USA/Europe
Language: English

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Already added :)

The kids and mystery thing in the lake make me think of The Quest (aka Frog Dreaming) but none of the rest fits.

@sirjonsnow It does seem a little bit similar, but its not that :)

I'm pretty sure you are describing 'The Boy From Andromeda', a six part TV series from 1991. I found a plot synopsis online; here is an excerpt:
- On a holiday to Mt Tarawera, a teenager (Jenny) finds an odd shard of metal. In the third episode of this sci-fi series, Jenny meets its owner 'Drom' — a survivor of an alien mission to deactivate a planet-annihilating space gun. Jenny and her friends find themselves under siege from a Predator-like 'Guardian' of the gun.
This show was produced a little later than in your estimation, so I should mention another series made a few years earlier in 1984. The Sci-fi series called 'The Children of the Dog Star' (both shows produced in New Zealand) has a similar plot; it's possible you confused the two. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
